# Google App Indexing - how to test it?

Tags: ios, swift, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

I've implemented all the things about App Indexing from google tutorial [Google App Indexing](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/app).
How can I now test result of search in safari? Should I have released app/can I test it in development environment without submitting to iTunes connect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [doc](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/test), "Once you've completed setup for App Indexing, you can verify your universal links prior to their appearance in Google Search by tapping a universal link in Safari on your device and making sure that it takes you to the right place in the app.

Note: You cannot test universal links on the XCode simulator."

Cheers,

MB

Answer (score 0):

Google app indexing testing can be done in two steps.

1) Universal link- This can be tested only in device. Click on the universal link to respective screen of app and ensure that universal link is deeplinked to app.

2) As part of google app indexing, the application icon will listed in google search result page. This can verified in itunes app/testflight build.